# How to style Material UI v5 native select drop down menu on chrome desktop?

Tags: material-ui

Do you have any idea which class should be targeted to style the background color of the drop-down? The issue is that in the light theme, the color is light, while in the dark theme, it is black. I want to make the black color a little bit lighter.

```js
const StyledNativeSelect = styled(NativeSelect)(({ theme }) => ({
    '&.MuiSelect-paper': {
      backgroundColor: 'lightblue', // Set the desired background color
      color: 'black', // Set the desired text color
    },
}));
  
  
<StyledNativeSelect>
  <option value={1}>Option 1</option>
  <option value={2}>Option 2</option>
  <option value={3}>Option 3</option>
</StyledNativeSelect>
```

Comment: It's the browser's native `select` element, so you don't have much leeway to style it.  You can style the underlying `select` itself (what you see when it's closed), but the dropdown portion is subject to your browser/OS's implementation of `select`.